# ASP.net, looking for a parameter to make sure there is 1 uppercase letter and a number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently looking for a fix for this issues im having in .NET. I am looking for a parameter to make sure there is 1 uppercase letter and a number.

My model property looks like this:

```cs
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment: Use a regex validator...

Comment: like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Add an RegularExpression attribute like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@".*\d.*[A-Za-z].*|.*[A-Za-z].*\d.*", ErrorMessage ="A letter and a digit is required")]
```

The regular expression tests the following:

```
    .*         Any character zero or more times
    \d         A digit
    .*         Any character zero or more times
    [A-Za-z]   A letter
    .*         Any character zero or more times

|   Or

    .*         Any character zero or more times
    [A-Za-z]   A letter
    .*         Any character zero or more times
    \d         A digit
    .*         Any character zero or more times
```

See https://regex101.com/r/WjSmUT/3